# Python (nltk) - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, nltk

I'm new to NLTK. I'm getting this error and I've searched around for encoding/decoding and specifically the UnicodeDecodeError but this error seems specific to the NLTK source code.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Python\Projects\Test\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(pos_tag(word_tokenize("John's big idea isn't all that bad.")))
  File "A:\Python\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 100, in pos_tag
    tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)
  File "A:\Python\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 779, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I go around fixing this error?
Here's what causes the error:

```
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
print(pos_tag(word_tokenize("John's big idea isn't all that bad.")))
```

Comment: It's the pos_tag function causing the error.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you show here that would generate the error. Print the `repr` of the string you're passing.

Comment: Returns the string but with `'` surrounding it.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't know what you mean, the function `pos_tag` is causing the error. I think the encoding error is generated on the pickle.load function. I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 5):

try this... NLTK 3.0.1 with Python 2.7.x

```
import io
f = io.open(txtFile, 'rU', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I use nltk 3.1 and Python 2.7.x.

Comment: This is great ! can you also explain why using io solves the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with you. I use Python 3.4 in Windows 7.

I had installed the "nltk-3.0.0.win32.exe" (from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk)). But when i installed the "nltk-3.0a4.win32.exe" (from [here](http://www.nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/)), my problem with nltk.pos_tag was solved. Check it.

EDIT: If the second link doesn't work, you can look [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/releases/tag/3.0a4).

Comment: the second link seems to be broken. Do you have any alternate links?

Answer (score -2):

Duplicate: [NLTK 3 POS_TAG throws UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590089/nltk-3-pos-tag-throws-unicodedecodeerror)

Long story short: NLTK isn't compatible with Python 3. You have to use NLTK 3 which sounds a bit experimental at this point.

Comment: I am using NLTK 3 and Python 3.4 and still get this error.

Answer (score -2):

Try using the module "textclean"

```
>>> pip install textclean
```

Python code

```
from textclean.textclean import textclean
text = textclean.clean("John's big idea isn't all that bad.")
print pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))
```

Comment: this module sounds like a _horrible_ idea.  it's particularly bad here, because the error is occurring when trying to decode a pickle — a structured data format that you will irreparably destroy if you try to blindly "clean" it.