# encoding error in pos tagging with nltk 3.0 on python 3.4

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I am using `NLTK 3.0` with Python 3.4 and cannot do POS tagging because of the following error:
I have read all [similar posts related to similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590089/nltk-3-pos-tag-throws-unicodedecodeerror), but could not find a way to solve the problem. most of the posts mention that upgrading to `NLTK 3.0` will solve the problem but I already have `NLTK 3.0`. According to these posts a change in the nltk's `data.py` solves the problem but `NLTK` people discourage doing that.
Here is my code:

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
pos_tag(word_tokenize("John's big idea isn't all that bad."))
```

and here is the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Is there any way to do it without manipulating `data.py`?
Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you download NLTK data using the provided interface (`nltk.download()` or something like this), and not by hand (in which case you might have data for Py2)? I have exactly the same setup as yours and can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of nltk_data, they provide two versions of the pickle files: one for Python 2 and one for Python 3. For example, there is one `english.pickle` at `nltk_data/taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger` and one at `nltk_data/taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/PY3`. The newest nltk handles this automatically by a decorator [`py3_data`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/compat.py).

In short, if you download the newest nltk_data, but don't have the newest nltk, it may load the wrong pickle file, raising the `UnicodeDecodeError` exception.

Note: suppose you already have the newest nltk, you may encounter some path error where you can see two "PY3"'s in the path of the pickle file. This may mean some developers were not aware of the `py3_data` and have handled the path redundantly. You can remove/revert the redundancy by yourself. See [this pull request](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/880) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problems with python3

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize("John's big idea isn't all that bad."))
[('John', 'NNP'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('big', 'JJ'), ('idea', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ("n't", 'RB'), ('all', 'DT'), ('that', 'DT'), ('bad', 'JJ'), ('.', '.')]
```

Check that you have the `utf-8` as your `sys.defaultencoding`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
```

If not there's a few things that you can do to explicitly specify the python's encoding, see [Why should we NOT use sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") in a py script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-we-need-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script)

Comment: Thank you alvas. But reload(sys) and sys.setdefaultencoding will throw me "undefined variable!". It seems that my python does not know functions "reload" and "setdefaultencoding". Do you know the reason  or is there any other way to change the default encoding? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your current output when you do `import sys; sys.getdefaultecnoding()` ?

Comment: The output error is: 
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. The output is "utf-8".